# Is it possible to re-export parts of a module while keeping the module namespace?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a library, within which I want to use a module `types` containing `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz`. I would like `Baz` to remain internal to the library, but re-export the other two for using them outside the library. For organizational purposes, I want the exported symbols to live inside the same module, in contrast to re-exporting the individual symbols. In other words, I want to re-export a subset of the module. Is there a neat solution to do this?

I know about `pub mod types;`, but that re-exports the entire module and since the symbols are pub for usage within the library, this also includes `Baz`. There is also `pub use types::{Foo, Bar};`, which only exports the symbols I want, but then they are placed in the library namespace instead of the module.

Comment: Move `types` to `types_internal` then `mod types { pub use types_internal::{Foo, Bar} }`